# Doubt with the conversion from output PID signal to PWM on inverted pendulum control problem

Tags: pwm, pid-controller

I am working on the design of a PID controller to control an inverted pendulum. The last days i got stuck in trying to understand the relationship between the PID's output, and how can relate it with the PWM signal (or percentage).
At first i supposed that it is necessary to measure the force that is generated by every percentage of PWM, so i can get a linear relation between both values. But then, looking for information on the internet and papers, i found that some of that papers say that the PID's output is the PWM signal, and the conversion is a scalling of the control signal in order to map it to a interval that the microcontroller can understand.
So, my question is, which of them is the correct answer?

Comment: Probably voltage is not directly proportional to force. In motion control it is normal to have position pid output as current pi input. Although in some systems current liop may be just skipped and system will work faster- with higher position bandwidth.

Comment: By the way, you will anyway have to tune pid factors

Comment: Your biggest stability problem is what comes between Vout from your PWM, and force at your actuator. Is there a lag, while V integrates to current, or is your V controlling current directly. An extra unwanted 90 degrees phase shift in your transfer response depends on the answer.

Comment: Are you doing a digital replacement of an existing analogue PID controller, or designing the digital controller from scratch?

Comment: I'm designing the digital controles, not doing a replacement, sorry if it wasn't clear. So there is not a Vout, because the micro send the pwm (it's an atmega 328p).

Answer (score 1):

> i found that some of that papers say that the PID's output is the PWM
>   signal

PWM represents an analogue signal just as the output of an ADC can represent an analogue signal. So, having a PID output that is purely analogue should be the same as having the same analogue signal represented by PWM. The whole point of PWM is that the operating frequency of PWM is high enough so that the recipient analogue/mechanical system does not see it as anything other than the original analogue signal.

In other words the receipient mechanical system is so slow at responding compared to the PWM switching frequency that it doesn't respond to the up/down nature of PWM but rather it just averages things out.

Go research class D audio amplifiers if you want a comparison.

Comment: Yes that Is my doubt. The pwm is a way of encoding a signal by a modulation. So, in my case that i'm using a digital PID, that its input is the error (an angle variation) and the output should be a control signal (in the analogue world is a force), i 'm able to only scale the output? Or i have to known which force correspond to pwm, and do a conversion?

Comment: You need to understand what the average magnitude of the pwm signal means I think you are asking? I can't tell you that but, largely, it doesn't matter providing it does the job and adequately makes the control system work.

Answer (score 0):

To control torque in both directions, Vout must be bipolar DC either single or double bridge using dual or single supplies respectively.

**However switched DC or PWM then low pass filtered (= Class D or higher) is the same as DC Average Voltage out. (so both are correct)**

side notes

> > The problem with motors is with friction and loading affect the ratio of loaded RPM to AVG DC voltage is very nonlinear. Velocity is actually much more nonlinear than k*RPM/V. It is more like an LED current is nonlinear with no current until Vf and then velocity is like an RC filter above this voltage but not below, so if you can make a circuit to model LED current with RC filter it can be inverted to correct your servo Voltage transfer function and compute stability margin.

*Big Hint* if you use 3 parts with LED, resistor and capacitor to model LED Current and not capacitor current with Vf Rs, Cp it will be better than using voltage control as a comparator input for your servo such that Vf is your stall voltage.

- Vavg= I* DCR which is proportional to static torque
- yet with no load , motor RPM/V is a constant above some stiction threshold.(like the LED current with large series R is in mA/V)
- but I and torque drops with velocity due to BEMF generated proportional to speed
- so proportional torque and angular momentum induced torque are opposing while shifting car position.

  > - Integration amplifies  position error * time, which has delayed
  >     feedback
  > - while derivative produces velocity error feedback for stability, but amplifies noise
  > - motor torque or current / mass affect affect proportion gain

Once you define your worst case initial conditions and desired response { erect capture time, center position error correction time, overshoot angle, car position and optimal IASE response (integrated average squared error response) only  then may start you start the design.

Try it manually then aim to design a system that is much faster and obviously more stable with lead-lag compensation and near 60 deg phase margin for PES and VES. Pos err signal and velocity error signal. Then estimate a current profile for acceleration, velocity and position error.

Test with random noise injected into the loop or swept sine, then external disturbances. Watch out for stiction and backlash delays.